# Trying REST but get PHP Fatal error: Class 'JObject' not found in

Tags: api, rest

I need make a query on civicrm project in joomla from REST. However, when I try:
http://localhost/joomla/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/extern/rest.php?entity=Contact&action=get&api_key=//user_key//&key=//site_key//
I just get:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'JObject' not found in /var/www/html/joomla/libraries/joomla/event/dispatcher.php on line 23
```

I already change manually the api_key in mysql database, but I just can't make the access between api and database.

How I was afraid that problem envolve permission issues, I try with cv command too. Here is the command:
cv api Contact.get debug=1 sequential=1

and exact same answer was showed up.

Can Someone help me to find the way toward resolve this problem?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

The question is old but for anyone searching for that error, see [CRM-21203](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-21203) and [PR-11609](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/11609) released in 5.1